# Display user photo within a User field type

Tags: users

I'm making a staff page with a User field type, so you select all the users you want displayed. I'm having trouble showing each user's photo though. This works:

```
{% for user in block.staffList.all() %}
   Image URL: {{ craft.assets.id(user.photoId).one().url }}
{% endfor %}
```

But seems far from the ideal solution. Is there a more graceful way to do this?

Comment: Ok, this works: `{{ user.photoUrl(user.id) }}`, but still seems a little redundant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works very simply. Note that the photo field is an **asset object**, not an array of asset objects.

```
{% for user in block.staffList.all() %}
   Image URL: {{ user.photo.getUrl() }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That's the ticket, thanks! Just a quick note: to skip over people that don't have photos, you can use `{% if member.photo is not null %}`

Comment: @Bryce Of course, you can still do eager loading and caching 
**{% for user in block.staffList.with(['photo']).all() %}** . I gave a short answer, Craft CMS has many methods to optimize.